# How to make Node.js NPM package to work with Typescript projects

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm the owner of "memphis-dev" npm package, I want Typescript users will be able to work with this package natively.
What can I do besides refactor the entire code into TS?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Comment: https://betterprogramming.pub/turn-javascript-into-typescript-compatible-packages-cb81820838ed